# Image Not Displaying in ASP.NET C# Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a png image in my Bin folder and it's net displaying in my web app. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    if (Calculation_Type.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
    {
        Generate_Flexible_ACN_Straight_Chart(ref vehicle);
        Legend.ImageUrl = "~/Bin/Flexible_Pavement_Subgrade_Strength.png";
    }
    else if (Calculation_Type.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
    {
        Generate_Flexible_ACR_Straight_Chart(ref vehicle);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in `wwwroot` named `images`. Place the string there, then in the view

`<img src="~/images/imageName.png />`

Comment: Src is not a member of Image. Can you help me with this?

Comment: What version of asp.net? Maybe that is a problem. Here is a short article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/image-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I have an asp.net core project. In it, I have a model with a property `public string ImagePath {get;set;}`. The value of that property is something like "/images/ImageName.png". Then in my view I have `<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImagePath)" />`

Comment: I'm using a if statement to display a correct image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Legend.ImageUrl = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Flexible_Pavement_Subgrade_Strength.png");
```

Comment: AppContext.BaseDirectory gave me an object reference error.

Answer (score 0):

put following code in web.config file. It will help you if it is permission related issue .

```
<location path="Image Path">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow user="*"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```